# Ubuntu based build agent in AKS cluster giving unexpected error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We were able to successfully add the deployment to Azuredevops Agent pool and could execute the pipeline on them by following the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#linux). But Its throwing strange error related to dynatrace for all the tasks which is getting executed inside them..

```
/opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.251.xxxxxxxxxx/any/nodejs/nodejsagent.js:2611
  const e = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8), d = 2 ** 32;
                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at module.js:676:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/azp/externals/node/bin/node', arguments '"/azp/_work/_tasks/PublishBuildArtifacts_2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe/1.158.3/publishbuildartifacts.js"'.
```

```
Note:- Same image is tried with the Docker standalone container and where the pipelines are getting executed successfully. Where as when we trigger the pipelines to the AKS based agents (using the same docker image), getting the above syntax error.
```

Adding the logs which we got from Build-Agent

---

/azp/_diag/Worker_20221108-092937-utc.log

```
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO AgentPluginManager] Loaded task plugin id 'ecxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-x-xxxxxxe' (main).
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO WorkerCommandManager] Enable plugin internal command extension.
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': '/azp/bin'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': '/azp'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Work': '/azp/_work'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': '/azp/bin'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Starting process:
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   File name: '/azp/bin/Agent.PluginHost'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Arguments: 'task "Agent.Plugins.Repository.CheckoutTask, Agent.Plugins"'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Working directory: '/azp/_work'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Require exit code zero: 'True'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Encoding web name: utf-8 ; code page: '65001'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Redirected STDIN: 'True'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Persist current code page: 'False'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   High priority process: 'False'
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Failed to update oom_score_adj for PID: 2515.
[2022-11-08 09:29:40Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/proc/2515/oom_score_adj' is denied.
---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWriteBuffer()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CloseStreamFromDispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.WriteProcessOomScoreAdj(Int32 processId, Int32 oomScoreAdj)
```

Comment: Have you checked your agent/worker logs to see if any clue related to this error?

Comment: yes.. added to issue above

Comment: I am getting same error while pushing to cloudfoundry.

Comment: You may need to run the build agent in another nodes where dynatrace is not running. Else dynatrace node version need to upgraded to node 10

Comment: @Vowneee I would like to confirm whether you have resolved this issue.